# How to plot tree without showing "samples" and "value" in random forest?

Tags: python, classification, random-forest, decision-tree

I want to make my trees simpler, wondering to plot trees without showing samples (e.g. 83) and values (e.g.[34,53,29,26])?   (I don't want the last two lines)
[image]

Here is a part of the current code of plotting trees.

```
X = df.iloc[:,0: -1] 
y = df.iloc[:,-1]    
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, stratify=y)
clf = RandomForestClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
.
.
.
.
# Here, I guess I need to add some commands.
plot_tree(clf.estimators_[5], 
          feature_names=X.columns,
          class_names=names, 
          filled=True, 
          impurity=True, 
          rounded=True,
          max_depth = 3)
```

Comment: what module do you use for plot it? If you can't find option in [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.plot_tree.html) then maybe it will need to digg in [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e1e6d09b/sklearn/tree/_export.py#L78) and change it.

Comment: digging in source code it seems you will have to write own code for this . You will have to get [BaseTreeExporter](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e1e6d09b/sklearn/tree/_export.py#L198) and remove parts which adds [samples](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e1e6d09b/sklearn/tree/_export.py#L320) and [value](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e1e6d09b/sklearn/tree/_export.py#L335)

Comment: @furas , there are a lot of modules to import. I put

 `from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier` ,
 `from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier`,
 `from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz`,
`from sklearn import tree`

Comment: @furas Yap, I think I need to dig in source code...
the current code is 
`RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None, min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=100, n_jobs=1, oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0, warm_start=False)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say we have a dataset like this, and we assign the matplotlib axis using `ax =`  argument:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import tree
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re
import matplotlib

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))

clf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0)
iris = load_iris()
clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
tree.plot_tree(clf.estimators_[0],ax=ax,
feature_names= iris.feature_names, class_names=iris.target_names)
```

Not sure if it is the best way, one way is to go under `ax.properties()` and edit the text:

```
def replace_text(obj):
    if type(obj) == matplotlib.text.Annotation:
        txt = obj.get_text()
        txt = re.sub("\nsamples[^$]*class","\nclass",txt)
        obj.set_text(txt)
    return obj
    
ax.properties()['children'] = [replace_text(i) for i in ax.properties()['children']]
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hey!!! Thanks for answering. It means so much.
I've tried it, and it works. 
The only thing is that the `feature names` is missing(sorry for that I didn't put the image with feature names, I edited just). Thus, I prefer to show `class=Risoluto` under `gini`. Do you know how to hide only samples and value? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: hi @Megan, see edited

Comment: Hey!! Thank you so much! That works.

Answer (score 0):

Small improvement to the above proposition from @StupidWolf.
If there are a lot of classes, `value = [...]` is split into multiple lines:

```
value = [100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
6, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 13]
```

So rather than substitution of text with `re.sub(...)`, I check which line starts `value` section:

```
def replace_text(obj):
  if type(obj) == matplotlib.text.Annotation:
    txt = obj.get_text()
    _lines = txt.splitlines()
    _result = []
    value_index = None
    class_index = None
    for i, _line in enumerate(_lines):
      if "value" in _line:
        value_index = i
      if "class" in _line:
        class_index = i
    assert value_index and class_index
    _result = _lines[:value_index] + _lines[class_index:]
    obj.set_text("\n".join(_result))
  return obj
```